# Only show data > (x) in a specified row SQL

Tags: sql

I have the below query and I only want column "Days since last pick" to display values greater than 15. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this?

```
select distinct srcloc "location",
    max(pckdte) "Date",
    sysdate - max(pckdte) "Days Since Last Pick",
    count(distinct inventory_view.lodnum) "# of Pallets in Location"
from pckwrk_view
left join inventory_view
    on pckwrk_view.srcloc = inventory_view.stoloc
join locmst
    on locmst.stoloc = inventory_view.stoloc
where srcloc like 'LP%A'
    and locmst.useflg = 1
group by srcloc
order by max(pckdte) asc
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific database you are using (e.g. "MySQL", "PostgreSQL", "SQLite", "SQL Server", etc)

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN returns regular INNER JOIN result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I only want column "Days since last pick" to display values greater than 15

If you want to display `null` for values that are less than 15, use a `case` expression:

```
select srcloc "location",
    max(pckdte) "Date",
    case when sysdate - max(pckdte) > 15 then sysdate - max(pckdte) end "Days Since Last Pick",
    count(distinct inventory_view.lodnum) "# of Pallets in Location"
from pckwrk_view
left join inventory_view
    on pckwrk_view.srcloc = inventory_view.stoloc
join locmst
    on locmst.stoloc = inventory_view.stoloc
where srcloc like 'LP%A'
    and locmst.useflg = 1
group by srcloc
order by max(pckdte) asc
```

On the other hand, if you want to remove these rows from your resultset, then use a `having` clause to filter on the aggregate expression:

```
select srcloc "location",
    max(pckdte) "Date",
    sysdate - max(pckdte) "Days Since Last Pick",
    count(distinct inventory_view.lodnum) "# of Pallets in Location"
from pckwrk_view
left join inventory_view
    on pckwrk_view.srcloc = inventory_view.stoloc
join locmst
    on locmst.stoloc = inventory_view.stoloc
where srcloc like 'LP%A'
    and locmst.useflg = 1
group by srcloc
having sysdate - max(pckdte) > 15
order by max(pckdte) asc
```

Note: `distinct` in a `group by` query is redundant, and somehow unclear; I removed it.

Comment: You are the man! Thank you for the response. Knew it would be something simple just did not know the statement to use. Thanks again!